# How to set Jest test retries globally

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Some of my test files in Jest are flaky.  Identifying individual files and adding `jest.retryTimes(2)` to the top of those files helps.  I would like to add that as a global setting rather than needing to add that line to the top of every file.

Is there a way to configure Jest so that it will always retry failed tests rather than needing to add that setting in each file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setupFilesAfterEnv:[array]` in your jest config file https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Make a setup file (e.g setup-jest.js) and include the `jest.retryTimes(2)` in there.

```
// setup-jest.js

jest.retryTimes(2)


// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.js'],
  ...
};
```